# One program, different on multiple computers

Tags: java

First of all, I want to ask you to ask as much information as possible to me to be able to help me out.

I've been creating an automatic reminder system which is able to create the reminder in PDF then automatically send it to the clients which you've chosen to be reminded.

The program is working perfectly fine, but once I try to start it on another computer, it does not work anymore. The following problems occur:

1. On one computer in Eclipse it does not even open the frame which handles the user input (telling the program which clients have to be reminded). The code is given below. An interesting point here is that I've tried to print a line if the actionPerformed method is running. It does NOT appear at all. So for some reason it is not listening to that whole method.

   ```
   if(starter.getAccess().equals("admin") || starter.getAccess().equals("god")){
                 menu = new JMenu("Aanmaningen");
                 menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
                 menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
                         "Debiteuren aanmanen");
                 menuBar.add(menu);
                 menu.addSeparator();
                 ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();
                 rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Pyxis Distribution B.V.");
                 rbMenuItem.setSelected(false);
                 rbMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
                 group2.add(rbMenuItem);
                 menu.add(rbMenuItem);
                 rbMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                   @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
                   @Override
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                       chosenComp = true;
                       f.getContentPane().add(new Main());
                         f.revalidate();
                         f.repaint();
                            Distrscherm obj = new Distrscherm();
                            obj.plannerJTable();
                   }

                 });
   ```

   2. On the other computers it was jarred and did open the menu, but did the JComboBox did not automatically complete the searchterms. It neither sent the mail. When clicking on the button **save and send** it didn't do anything. The codes are shown below.

**This is the code which handles automatic completion (pretty basic code)**

```
    public AutoComboBox() {

    setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(myVector));
    setSelectedIndex(-1);
    setEditable(true);
    JTextField text = (JTextField) this.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
    text.setFocusable(true);
    text.setText("");
    text.addKeyListener(new ComboListener(this, myVector));
    setMyVector();
}

/**
 * set the item list of the AutoComboBox
 * @param patternExamples an String array
 */
public static void setKeyWord(Object[] patternExamples) {
    AutoComboBox.keyWord = patternExamples;
    setMyVectorInitial();
}

private void setMyVector() {
    int a;
    for (a = 0; a < keyWord.length; a++) {
        myVector.add(keyWord[a]);
    }
}

private static void setMyVectorInitial() {
    myVector.clear();
    int a;
    for (a = 0; a < keyWord.length; a++) {

        myVector.add(keyWord[a]);
    }
```

**This is the code which handles the SAVE button**

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                Writer obj1 = new Writer(getTableData(table), "./planningdagelijks/week.csv");
                for(int i =0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    Datareader.Runner(model.getValueAt(i, 0));
                    internalfile obj2 = new internalfile();
                    obj2.intern();
                    try {
                        maildata.Reader((String)model.getValueAt(i, 0));
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Pdfgenerator.Filegenerator((String)model.getValueAt(i, 0));
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Sadly I think that we would need all your code to understand the problem you are facing entirely, but then the question would be way too broad. If you can create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then we might be able to help

Comment: There are too many variables too look at here and possibilities

Comment: Yes I totally understand that boys. Problem here is that it exists of about 15 files. Do you have a general idea how it could have different responses on different pcs?

Comment: May be related to "./planningdagelijks/week.csv". it's static. Btw ths is hard to debug.

Comment: Yes it's very hard to debug, but I would love to know how it is even possible to have different reactions. If I know the underlying theory I might be able to debug it myself..

Comment: Your real problem here is that you don't have enough classes yet ;-) ... seriously: you are wildly mixing your "business logic" with the UI parts. All of that should be fully separated. That would also enable yourself to properly unit test things, instead of relying to throw everything together, to then to functional testing on the component as a whole ... the problem is that somebody could sit down with you an look into your code for hours in order to fix all the issues that are potentially in there. But that is out of the scope of this community.

Comment: I would suggest that you look for some real person (best with some experience) to review your stuff. Anything else is just putting band aids on symptoms.

Comment: Gotcha, in that case I'm very sorry for asking. However, could I change my question to "How is it possible that there are different reactions"? I want to know the underlying theory so I could think about it myself.

Comment: And isn't there a reason why the printline isn't running? It doesn't contain many lines.

Comment: This is typical for unhandled exceptions (this includes printing to standard out).   I would have a close look at what happens if a runtime exception occurs.